# Include iframe on click of jquery tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have below code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css"/>
  ul.tabs {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    height:22px;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:8px 0 -50px 0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float:left;
    height:21px;
    line-height:21px;
    border:1px solid #999;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background:#ADD8E6;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    margin:0 2px -1px 0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    display:block;
    font-size:1em;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    outline:none;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:8px;
    border-top-left-radius:8px;
    border-top-right-radius:8px;
    padding:0 20px;
}

ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background:#ADD8E6;
}

html ul.tabs li.active,html ul.tabs li.active a:hover {
    background:#fff;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}

.tabContainer {
    border:1px solid #999;
    overflow:hidden;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:0;
    border-radius:8px;
    border-top-left-radius:0;
}

.labelStyle{
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:1.5em
}

.tabContent {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:20px;
}

.chkAlign{
    margin-left:143px
}


  </style>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

        //hiding tab content except first one
        $(".tabContent").not(":first").hide();
        // adding Active class to first selected tab and show
        $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 

        // Click event on tab
        $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
            // Removing class of Active tab
            $("ul.tabs li.active").removeClass("active");
            // Adding Active class to Clicked tab
            $(this).addClass("active");
            // hiding all the tab contents
            $(".tabContent").hide();       
            // showing the clicked tab's content using fading effect
            $($('a',this).attr("href")).fadeIn('slow');

            return false;
        });



});

  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="tabs">
   <li><a href="#tab1">SEO</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2">Attributes</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab3">Classification SIC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabContainer">
   <div id="tab1" class="tabContent">
    <iframe style="width:90%" src=" http://10.204.66.70:8080/myApp/myUI.do?geo=us&tab=sic&gid=138370"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id="tab2" class="tabContent">
    <iframe style="width:90%" src=" http://10.204.66.70:8080/myApp/myUI.do?geo=us&tab=some&gid=235"></iframe>
   </div>

    <div id="tab3" class="tabContent">
    <iframe style="width:90%" src=" http://10.204.66.70:8080/myApp/myUI.do?geo=uk&tab=sic&gid=789"></iframe>
   </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

On click of each tab, i need render some page in an iframe. But above code is not working. Am i doing anything wrong here?

How can i do this?

Comment: Any error on console?

Answer (score 0):

first thing first it may be that the header send by the iframe is X-Frame-Options so the website refuses to response in the iframe.

your url seems wrong, space avec the double quote of the src and the port of the website should be followed by a /

try to replace your adresses by a local file on your post. Your code should work.

Comment: AMS, i corrected my urls. It is working only on page load. I have a code to show first tab on page load. Only this is working. If i click on tab2, no result, again if i go back to tab 1 then also no result. If i refresh then first tabs content is shown on page load.

Comment: seems like a different problem to me, try refreshing the iframe in javascript maybe